# i cann't install logpy with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

When I try `pip install logpy` those errors appear. How can I fix it? Thanks so much!

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\tran quoc bao\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\TRANQU~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gs_uzbje\\logpy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\TRANQU~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gs_uzbje\\logpy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\TRANQU~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gs_uzbje\logpy\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\TRANQU~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gs_uzbje\logpy\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\TRANQU~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gs_uzbje\logpy\setup.py", line 6, in <module>
        long_description = open('README.rst').read(),
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'README.rst'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: What do you think about using an alternative to `logpy`? As explained, this one is will be most likely a regrettable choice.

Answer (score 0):

The last time this module was updated was in 2012. There's an [issue](https://github.com/MHordecki/LogPy/issues/2) from 2016 that reports the problem you mentioned. Take aways:

- The package is broken. This particular error can be easily fixed by cloning the repository and adding `README.rst`. I'd not go this way, as most likely there are more issues. It's hard to say how it would work with modern Python.
- The module provides "logging alternative" to `logging` module. If you don't like the vanilla version, try [loguru](https://github.com/Delgan/loguru), *enjoyable logging in Python*.